# How do you connect subclasses to superclass in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, rdbms

We have a payment type entity as the super class. We have Cash and Card as the sub classes. If we were to make these tables in SQL, how would we connect the sub classes to the super class?

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions 
( 
  transactionID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
  customerID INT FOREIGN KEY references LoyaltyCustomers(customerID), 
  total MONEY, 
  timePlaced time,
  datePlaced date 
) 

CREATE TABLE Cash 
(
  cashID INT NOT NULL, 
  transactionID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY references Transactions(transactionID), 
  PRIMARY KEY (cashID, transactionID) 
) 

CREATE TABLE Card 
(
  cardID INT NOT NULL, 
  transactionID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY references Transactions(transactionID), 
  PRIMARY KEY (cardID, transactionID) 
)
```

Comment: You provide way to less info. What columns do you need and how do the 2 tables differ infomation-wise? There is no general answer to that broad question.

Comment: The payment method is a mandatory, or relationship so you can either pay with cash or pay with a card. We were trying to use foreign keys in the subclasses (cash and card), which then refer to the primary key in the superclass (paymentType). In SQL Server, we couldn't get a code that works out.

Comment: If you add what you have to the question then we can have a look and help you fix it.

Comment: CREATE TABLE Transactions ( transactionID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, customerID INT FOREIGN KEY references LoyaltyCustomers(customerID), total MONEY, timePlaced time, datePlaced date ) CREATE TABLE Cash ( cashID INT NOT NULL, transactionID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY references Transactions(transactionID), PRIMARY KEY (cashID, transactionID) ) CREATE TABLE Card ( cardID INT NOT NULL, transactionID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY references Transactions(transactionID), PRIMARY KEY (cardID, transactionID) )

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need extra info that differs cash fron card payments you can use a single column instead of 2 extra tables

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions 
( 
  transactionID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
  total MONEY, 
  placed datetime,
  [type] tinyint NOT NULL CHECK ([type] IN(1,2))
)
```

If `type = 1` could be cash. `type = 2` could be credit. Or you could use the `bit` data type if you only have 2 types of payments: card and cash.